# Laravel websocket bug

Tags: laravel, websocket

Everything is done according to your guide, re-read several times, looked at a bunch of answers on Google, but my error is not fixed! Here is a mistake:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFuw4.png)
enclose code:

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Dashboard\Http\Middleware\Authorize;

return [

```
/*

 * Set a custom dashboard configuration

 */

'dashboard' => [

    'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),

],



/*

 * This package comes with multi tenancy out of the box. Here you can

 * configure the different apps that can use the webSockets server.

 *

 * Optionally you specify capacity so you can limit the maximum

 * concurrent connections for a specific app.

 *

 * Optionally you can disable client events so clients cannot send

 * messages to each other via the webSockets.

 */

'apps' => [

    [

        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),

        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

        'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),

        'capacity' => null,

        'enable_client_messages' => true,

        'enable_statistics' => true,

    ],

],



/*

 * This class is responsible for finding the apps. The default provider

 * will use the apps defined in this config file.

 *

 * You can create a custom provider by implementing the

 * `AppProvider` interface.

 */

'app_provider' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\ConfigAppProvider::class,



/*

 * This array contains the hosts of which you want to allow incoming requests.

 * Leave this empty if you want to accept requests from all hosts.

 */

'allowed_origins' => [

    //

],



/*

 * The maximum request size in kilobytes that is allowed for an incoming WebSocket request.

 */

'max_request_size_in_kb' => 250,



/*

 * This path will be used to register the necessary routes for the package.

 */

'path' => 'laravel-websockets',



/*

 * Dashboard Routes Middleware

 *

 * These middleware will be assigned to every dashboard route, giving you

 * the chance to add your own middleware to this list or change any of

 * the existing middleware. Or, you can simply stick with this list.

 */

'middleware' => [

    'web',

    Authorize::class,

],



'statistics' => [

    /*

     * This model will be used to store the statistics of the WebSocketsServer.

     * The only requirement is that the model should extend

     * `WebSocketsStatisticsEntry` provided by this package.

     */

    'model' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Models\WebSocketsStatisticsEntry::class,



    /*

     * Here you can specify the interval in seconds at which statistics should be logged.

     */

    'interval_in_seconds' => 60,



    /*

     * When the clean-command is executed, all recorded statistics older than

     * the number of days specified here will be deleted.

     */

    'delete_statistics_older_than_days' => 60,



    /*

     * Use an DNS resolver to make the requests to the statistics logger

     * default is to resolve everything to 127.0.0.1.

     */

    'perform_dns_lookup' => false,

],



/*

 * Define the optional SSL context for your WebSocket connections.

 * You can see all available options at: http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

 */

'ssl' => [

    /*

     * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which

     * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the

     * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained

     * in a separate file specified by local_pk.

     */

    'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),



    /*

     * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for

     * certificate (local_cert) and private key.

     */

    'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),



    /*

     * Passphrase for your local_cert file.

     */

    'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),

],



/*

 * Channel Manager

 * This class handles how channel persistence is handled.

 * By default, persistence is stored in an array by the running webserver.

 * The only requirement is that the class should implement

 * `ChannelManager` interface provided by this package.

 */

'channel_manager' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManagers\ArrayChannelManager::class,
```

];

return [

```
/*

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Default Broadcaster

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

|

| This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the

| framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to

| any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.

|

| Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"

|

*/



'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),



/*

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Broadcast Connections

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

|

| Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used

| to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of

| each available type of connection are provided inside this array.

|

*/



'connections' => [



    'pusher' => [

        'driver' => 'pusher',

        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

        'options' => [

            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),

            'useTLS' => true,

        ],

     'host' => '127.0.0.1',

     'post' => 6001,

     'scheme' => 'https'

    ],



    'redis' => [

        'driver' => 'redis',

        'connection' => 'default',

    ],



    'log' => [

        'driver' => 'log',

    ],



    'null' => [

        'driver' => 'null',

    ],



],
```

];

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({

```
broadcaster: 'pusher',

key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,

cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,

wsHost: window.location.hostname,

wsPort: 6001,
```

});

PUSHER_APP_ID=1323123

PUSHER_APP_KEY=312313123

PUSHER_APP_SECRET=312313

PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

APP_URL=http://smart-php.design

My site has https, maybe you need to configure it somehow? Therefore, an error occurs, before a “message” was sent to me, but after my manipulations everything again broke down.

Here is the url: http://smart-php.design

I will be extremely grateful for the support!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please format your code properly and try to properly formulate the question

Comment: [Why you should not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup ssl certificate (refer to their [document](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl) on ssl) otherwise just turn off the encryption and serve over WS.